# Setting a mode to a pin requires root permissions

Tags: gpio, ssh, raspbian-stretch, permissions

I’m trying to change pin mode on RPI (with Raspbian) – it works when I invoke those commands

```
sudo chown root.gpio /dev/gpiomem
sudo chmod g+rw /dev/gpiomem
```

but after every restart I have to execute them because without this I have this error:

```
“Setting a mode to a pin requires root permissions. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/sys/class/gpio/gpio21/direction' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied”
```

How can I persist those permissions?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Raspbian (November 2018)

Comment: You should edit useful information into your question.  People shouldn't need to read the comments.  You should just add your user to group gpio.  Nothing else should be required on Raspbian, i.e. a one off `sudo adduser pi gpio`.

Comment: I updated my question when I commented post and pi user is already in this group